# How to get proper url rewriting with proper format in localhost?

Tags: php, localhost

**My .htaccess file as below,**

```
DirectoryIndex routing.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase  /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/routing\.php[\s?] [NC]

RewriteRule ^ Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^Milan_Mvc/?$ Milan_Mvc/routing.php [L,NC]
```

**By Appling above code I got url like below,**

```
http://localhost/Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/?name=about
```

**in above,there after "?",data is not in valid format as I want like this,**

```
http://localhost/Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/about/
```

**So please give your suggestion with proper ReWriting Rule for above code**

*ThankYou in Advance !!!*

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA]
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I haven't full knowledge about Rewriting url,so give RewriteRule which,i can directly apply to my code

Comment: That's why I preffered giving you an URL.